# Not able to connect to SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, sqlconnection

I am trying to connect to SQL Server Management Studio with Azure server, but an error happens:

> A network related or instance specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

I am using my credentials too.

- server name : faena4vikq.database.windows.net
- username : "Myusername"
- password : "Mypassword"

I have also added my IP address in Azure server configuration panel.

My services are also running.

In Azure database connection string is also showing same :

```
Server=tcp:faena4vikq.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mjdData;User ID=mjduser@faena4vikq;Password={your_password_here};Trusted_Connection=False;Encrypt=True;Connection Timeout=30;
```

What do I need to check else?

Comment: Did you open port 1433?

Comment: Yes, I opened both (1433 and 1434) from outbound rules in firewall -> advance security

Comment: For them, I have used random names. (SQLRile1 and SQLRule2). I guess that should not be a problem

Comment: Those should be inbound rules, not outbound.

Comment: Tried... But still same error

Comment: Sql server agent (MSSQLSERVER) is not started. When I try to start it. It gives alerts me, "service started and stoped automatically, because it is not used by any program ".

Comment: Hmm agent service is usually tied to db engine service. Are you sure that is started?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/789616/sql-server-services-overview-anyone

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116297/discussion-between-keval-patel-and-joe-c).

Comment: I'm confused, are you using the Azure SQL Database (Database as a Service) or do you have a VM with SQL Server that you control running the server?  If it is the first, you will need to add you ip to the server firewall rule: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-configure-firewall-settings/ if it is the second, try this link: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-windows-portal-sql-server-provision/#FW

Comment: I am using first one. And I already added my IP in server firewall rule.

Answer (score 0):

Is that your real server name? It seems that is does not exist.

Thanks,
Mihaela

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer

Comment: I removed, and created another server. "z788b5csgc.database.windows.net"